# Web crawling error using Python at 'whoscored.com'

Tags: python, soap, beautifulsoup

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
user_agent = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get("https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/England-Premier-League", headers=user_agent)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')


print(soup)
```

I'm trying to do webcrawling on 'whoscored.com' but I can't get all the HTML Tell me the solution.

Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 946001050011236585-61439481461474967

this is result.

Comment: What's the HTTP response code? They are likely blocking you from crawling their website.

Comment: You are dealing with `Incapsula `

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/2/England-Premier-League'
sada = browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

There is a couple of issues here. The root cause is that the website you are trying to scrape knows you're not a real person and is blocking you. Lots of websites do this simply by checking headers to see if a request is coming from a browser or not `(robot)`. However, this site looks like they use `Incapsula`, which is designed to provide more sophisticated protection